# Why video made with iOS can't be read on Android but the inverse works

Tags: video, ios

I'm currently testing why a video made with an iOS device does not seems to work on my Galaxy S3.

Here's the file info from ffmpeg :

**Video took with Galaxy S3:**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20130715_151126.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2013-07-15 13:12:08
  Duration: 00:00:41.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17143 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17015 kb/s, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2013-07-15 13:12:08
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, 123 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-07-15 13:12:08
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

**Video took with iPhone 4S:**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'trim.BE866F9A-654A-4C76-AC43-5CDF4923A2F0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2013-11-15 12:44:22
    encoder         : 6.0
    encoder-fra     : 6.0
    date            : 2013-05-31T14:22:11+0200
    date-fra        : 2013-05-31T14:22:11+0200
    model           : iPhone 4S
    model-fra       : iPhone 4S
    make            : Apple
    make-fra        : Apple
  Duration: 00:00:21.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4221 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-15 12:44:22
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 4147 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2013-11-15 12:44:22
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

They seems to be fairly the same video and audio encoding using h264/aac
The only thing that differs I can see are :

- The resolution (It should not be a problem)
- The FPS (should not be a problem)
- In iOS the audio is stream 0:0 while in Android it is 0:1

The thing is, a video took with a Galaxy S3 does work fine on iOS without recoding it.

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Have you tried using a different video player?

Comment: I would like to use the default player, since it is to create an Cross-Platform App iOS - Android, I don't want to ask Android user to download another player in order to play it. And since video should be saved on the users gallery, I can't even do a Player myself... I would have to re-encode the video.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want your users to download a player to show the videos, then you have no other choice but to create videos with the [H.264 Baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles) profile. This is because the stock Android player [does not support anything higher](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

iOS on the other hand does support the Main and High profile. While not listed in [the iOS specifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html), the iPhone 4S and upwards [should support it](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post9_encoding_h264_for_ios_with_main_and_high_profile/index.html).

It could very well be that your Samsung's video app records High profile video and can also play it (because Samsung included a non-stock player*). In any case, converting to Baseline profile would ensure that the video is playable on all devices.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 output.mp4
```

That should do it. You can change the CRF parameter to change quality. Check [the x264 encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more.

<sub>* Disclaimer: I don't own a Samsung Android phone. No idea if they have a non-stock player.</sub>